# Php How to make a multidimensional array as a single string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

```
array(array("Color", "red" ), array("Ram", "4GB" ) );
```

Convert this multidimensional array into a string like this

```
Color=red&Ram=4GB
```

Comment: Its always worth a search before asking

Comment: Its not a key value pair thats the problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly its not a key value pair thats the problem

Comment: Loop over it, have a new array and make the key value pair thing and use http_build_query in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearrange the input array a bit and then you can use `http_build_query()`

```
$sq = array(array("Color", "red" ), array("Ram", "4GB" ) );

$aa = [];

foreach( $sq as $s ) {
    $aa[$s[0]] = $s[1];
}

echo http_build_query($aa);
```

RESULT

```
Color=red&Ram=4GB
```

Comment: That worked thank you soo much ☺️☺️

Answer (score 3):

As long as `0` is the key name and `1` is the value, then just create a single dimension indexed on the first element and build the query string:

```
$string = http_build_query(array_column($array, 1, 0));
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple approach, Loop over `$params` and again loop for each `$param` then get `$key` `$value` pair concatenate them with `=` and store them in an array `$query`. last but not least join them together with `&`.

```php
$params = [['color'=>'red'],['RAM'=>'4gb']];

$query = [];
foreach ($params as $param) {
    foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
        array_push($query, "$key=$value");
    }
}
echo join("&",$query);
```

**Result:**

```
color=red&RAM=4gb
```

Comment: Thats not a key value pair both are values